# mysql join 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

How can I join three mysql tables which have one common column (id), For example, Select a, b from Table1, select c,d from table2, select e,f from table3, where id=x
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
 SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.c, t2.d, t3.e, t3.f
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) 
  JOIN table3 t3 ON (t1.id = t3.id)
  ORDER BY t1.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.c, t2.d, t3.e, t3.f
FROM `table1` t1
JOIN `table2` t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
JOIN `table3` t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
WHERE t1.id = x
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `table1`.`a`,`table2`.`c` .....
FROM `table1` JOIN `table2` USING(`id`) JOIN `table3` USING(`id`)
WHERE `id` = x
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.c, t2.d, t3.e, t3.f
  FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id
   AND t2.id = t3.id
   AND t3.id = x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 (select any col from any table ) 
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2,t3 
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.id = t3.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT product_details.product_id, product_name.pro_name,categories.cat_name
        FROM product_details
        INNER JOIN product_name
        ON product_details.product_id=product_name.id INNER JOIN categories ON product_details.categories_id=categories.id order by product_details.id;
```