# Can you help me to formulate a SQL query to join 3 tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure how to do this so I'm asking it here...

I have 3 tables in my database with structure like this..

table:contact ----- rows: contact_id, firstname

table:groups ------rows: group_id, group_name

table:groupmembership ------ rows: contact_id, group_id

The association between between "contact_id" and "group_id" in the table "group_membership" reflects a contact that is in a particular group.

What I need to do is take a contact_id, and display which groups he is a member of in a dropdown list.  I'll eventually use this dropdown list to post the group_id to a page that diplays the group info.

Can anyone help me with how to formulate the MySQL query?

Comment: What is your problem in formulating the query? With which part you need help?

Comment: This question has many duplicates. One of them is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777760/mysql-join-3-tables?rq=1

Comment: That link did not answer my question.  I read that one already, as well as many other explanations.  I thought my question was explained very well, I'll try to be more clear though... The table "group_membership" is acting as a hub of information associating data from the other two tables.  What I need to do is take that data from "group_membership" and glean the "group_name" and "contact_name" from the other two tables.

I guess it's irrelevant now since my question is deemed "Not a real question".  lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select by user_id:

```
SELECT group_name, group_id
FROM groupmembership gm
INNER JOIN groups g ON g.group_id = gm.group_id
WHERE gm.contact_id = 4711
```

If you want to select by user's firstname:

```
SELECT group_name, group_id
FROM groupmembership gm
INNER JOIN groups g ON g.group_id = gm.group_id
INNER JOIN contact c ON c.contact_id = gm.contact_id
WHERE c.firstname LIKE 'TheHe';
```